# Which technique is better Win32 Named Pipe or WinSock 2?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, winsock, named-pipes

I have Visual C/C++ program which is going to communicate with other Programs(both local and Non-local) over the Intra-net(LAN).Previously I used win32 Memory Mapped Files/Events to communicate locally. Now I want to extend my program to support over network communication.

Since MMF doesn't support network Inter-process communication(term should be Intra-Process Com') it's obvious I have to use Win32 Named Pipes Or WinSock2 mechanisms in order to transferring data through local network.

Here my only intention to build a Intra-network Process communication only, So **which mechanism perform better  with respect to following factors:**

- Single Server Multiple Clients - (Duplex -> Transmit & Receive from both end)
- Transmit data through slow Local Area Network
- Server is basic Visual C/C++ Program and Client end is DLL loaded by another process therefore functionalities should be light-weight.
- Transmission Speed (Data should transmit between process with higher frequency)

Which mechanism should be implemented ? Named-Pipes or WinScoket2 ?
Thank you.

Comment: Named pipes outside of the local host are over the TCP/IP stack anyway. I can't imagine the performance would be any *better* once you've crossed that threshold, and plenty of avenues to think it could get worse (namely, the overhead of pipes over tcp/ip).

Comment: @WhozCraig you prefer WinSock ?

Comment: WinSock is how they call the library that does sockets for Windows, there is no TCP/IP in Windows without WinSock. That being said, named pipes will use WinSock to handle traffic over network, it has no choice. Named pipes add an incredible layer of complications to the communication. File and Printer Sharing must be enabled on the host for it to be accessible, Windows Firewall must be allowing connections, and you need to have access to the server which may require use of Windows credentials and proper configuration of the whole thing. I would avoid using that.

Comment: @Havenard what do your prefer ? regarding performance ?

Comment: Winsock. Named pipes hold all the data at the server, and probably still use NetBEUI over TCP. Pretty antique stuff, dating from before Gates believed in the Internet.

Comment: It cant get faster than old fashion TCP connection with sockets, any "alternative" will use that beneath whatever interface it offers to you anyway, so you can just cut straight to the point and use it to make your own intercommunication interface.